# Blender doesn't detect CUDA/TitanX

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

After updating to Blender 2.78 on my other PC it does not detect the GPU. It is running on a Win7 x64bit system, card in question is a Maxwell TitanX, which from the official Nvidia spec list is a 5.2 cuda supporting GPU.

Here are some screen caps after doing a clean driver install.

[image: Blender System Properties]
[image: nVidia Control Panel]

Comment: Did you install the Cuda Drivers installed?

Comment: Have you tried to even select it by yourself in Blender? It might not automatically enable it.

Comment: @SamirRahamtalla Yes, I have. installed them.

Comment: @Hendriks3D Do you mean forcing Blender to use it via the Nvidia control panel?

Comment: Honestly I think it's a Blender error. Try reinstalling Blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hendriks3D Yes, it appears to be a Blender error. Something appears to have went wrong with the files and Blender wasn't detecting the GPU.

After a clean install everything is running ok. Do not know why it worked now and before it didn't work.